# manifest.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service

I have a react application that works fine locally. However after I deploy to Azure Web App I get following error in console:

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)

I can see the purpose is when people install the app on a mobile, then REACT renders differently dependent on the devise. I can also see it is located in the index.html file:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

As my app is a web site does this file has any effect? Can I just delete it or should I try to solve the error? And if yes how?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I need the manifest.json since I want my app to be a PWA. Did anyone solved this?

Comment: I already tried updating the homepage in package.json and creating .env file but that didnt work

Answer (score 5):

Are you using create-react-app?

The manifest makes only sense when you want that your users can install your app so it works without an internet connection e.g. Thats in the end a [Progressive Web App](https://web.dev/what-are-pwas/). So for you it's probably fine to just remove the line.

(under which path does your app serve? Maybe you have to specify a base path: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Yes I am using create-react-app. Thanks for the response. As it is a normal web page I just remove the line as I have no need for offline functionality:D

Answer (score 0):

For production apps, you have to target `build` for the public in `firebase.json` like the following:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build", // Here you have to make changes.
    "ignore": [
     "firebase.json",
     "**/.*",
     "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
     {
       "source": "**",
       "destination": "/index.html"
     }
    ],
    "headers": [
     {"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this?

go to `angular.json`

add `manifest.json location`  in assets

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
          ],
```

[image: my angular.json file]

restart dev server using
`ng serve`